# Windows control pannel sharing protected by password radio button

Tags: windows, powershell, network-shares, file-sharing

> How i can manage '**Sharing protected by password**' 
>   option (radio button) in Windows control panel with powershell ?

I can modify the network profile type with :

> Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory ...

And disable (or enable) File and Printer sharing with :

> Get-Service -Name LanmanServer | Stop-Service ...

Now I want to enable or disable '**Sharing protected by password**' option in '**All networks**' section programmaticly and without rebooting my computer(And learning how access work for everyone and anonymous accounts.).

Thank you

Comment: Which? Where? What? Please include more and relevant information in the question so that we understand what you are asking. Rather than asking about a specific radio button, tell us what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'm going to give you some starting points but it appears you will need to set the Guest account with NO PASSWORD and make a registry change so this may all be needed to automate. See here for the potential registry settings which you can script out to change accordingly: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/75d6e3cd-f5bd-4f38-8f98-99bc20180966/turn-on-off-passwordprotected-sharing-using-regedit-or-registry-key?forum=win10itprosecurity and figure out how to enable Guest and set it with a blank password via command like e.g. `net user guest *` and press `Enter` twice.

Comment: Again, these are some starting points for you or others only for some ideas that **I have not verified** and just stumbled upon with brief research while I have time for this inquiry but this may be the way to do it unless there's an easier way to script it out or something that you can do via command line, PowerShell, etc.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer and so of your time. I worked and I read some answers and checked locally: HKLM \ SECURITY needs to be edited. I found the Duplicate-Token powershell script on Sysinternal but I did not read it correctly and I do not know how it works for safe script execution. I did some tests on my computer and saw the guest account activated when I turned off the sharing option. I think I have already read your link but I will read again. Thanks again and sorry for my english.